# What Does HRT mean on Scanner Tool?

Tags: wrangler, scan-tool

I was doing an I/M Readiness Test on my Jeep, and saw 'HRT' as one of the failed systems. I've tried googling but have only gotten unclear answers. Does anyone know what this is?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was wondering whether this should have been HTR for an oxygen sensor heater.

I then found this from [here](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51LFhDDb9sL.pdf) -

[image]

It would fit that the O2 sensor and O2 heater both have red crosses against them.

Comment: yea I thought this was the case, but when looking this up it was a headache. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @WhiplashGamz - I see you selected this as the answer, but if it helps you, consider also upvoting it, please.

Comment: I just did. although at the time I selected it as the answer, it said I wasn't able to yet.